# Handling tabs, actionbar, activities and fragments

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator, android-fragments, android-activity

I am facing problem in designing following scenario :

1. Showing 3 tabs for contact-lists (all, friends and family)
2. All tabs would contain contact-list as per the groups
3. Any contact could be selected and viewed but should be in the same tab (either all,family or frnds)
4. In short, tabs should be available globally.

Here, I decided to use `ActionBar` and to change the view by using fragments to be called from `onTabSelected()` of `TabListener`; in which I was confused as I have to keep only single activity but multiple fragments. 
'Keeping single activity' is this a standard / valid approach ? Please suggest.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you have to use activity group with tab bar in which tab will remain available globally

Comment: @Sumant `ActivityGroup` is deprecated, can you please suggest anything further ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should have a single Activity and have a container(could be an empty LinearLayout) in which fragments are replaced depending on the tab selected.

Comment: Yeah i have done so. But I was unsure that keeping a single activity through out the application is valid approach or not. Can you please tell me that whether the `GC` would work properly if single activity is kept through entire application ?

Comment: I am not very much sure about this, but somewhere I have read, that GC works when the activity goes to background, so if I keep only single activity it might not come into picture. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Creating New activities is more expensive than having a single activity and reusing it

Comment: Thanks, for the suggestion; but I won't be _reusing_ the activity, rather it would be continuosly used by the app and fragments would be switched, as you know the scenario. Will it be fine still ?

Comment: FYI you don't need an empty layout to attach to. Just specify `android.R.id.content` as the attachment target.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is late, but I used a tabhost with fragments to do something similar. Here's a nice tutorial.
http://thepseudocoder.wordpress.com/2011/10/04/android-tabs-the-fragment-way/